# Find byte[] in byte[] with Java

Tags: java, array, search

I made a search method because I want to use binary data like PNG files. The point of this is to be able to find strings like `IEND` in a PNG file. I think it works properly. Any improvements/fixes would be appreciated.

```
public static int findString(byte[] in, byte[] find) {
        boolean done = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
            if(in[i] == find[0]) {
                for(int ii = 1; ii < find.length; i++) {
                    if(in[i+ii] != find[ii]) break;
                    else if(ii==find.length-1) done = true;
                }
                if(done) return i-1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to look for a particular chunk of bytes in a PNG file, don't scan it naïvely byte by byte.  Not only would it be [slow](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Rationale.html#R.Chunk-layout), you could also accidentally match some data that happens to look like a marker.

Instead, you should take advantage of the [chunk layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5Chunk-layout) described in the PNG specification.  Each chunk is tagged with a type and a length.  If the tag is of a type that you are not interested in, seek ahead to the next chunk — the length field will tell you how many bytes to skip.

Answer (score 7):

1. I might have misunderstood something but both of these tests fail:

   ```
   @Test
   public void test3() {
       byte[] in = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
       byte[] find = { 3, 4, 5 };
       assertEquals(2, findString(in, find)); // returns -1
   }

   @Test
   public void test5() {
       byte[] in = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
       byte[] find = { 4, 5, 6 };
       assertEquals(3, findString(in, find)); // returns -1
   }
   ```

   I think you should increase `ii++` here instead of `i`:

   > ```
   > for(int ii = 1; ii < find.length; i++) {
   > ```

   So, try to use variables which are easer to tell apart from each other.
2. Anyway, don't reinvent the wheel, there is a library for that! [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a [`Bytes`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html#indexOf%28byte%5b%5d,%20byte%5b%5d%29) class with the following method:

   > ```
   > public static int indexOf(byte[] array, byte[] target)
   > ```
   >
   > Returns the start position of the first occurrence of the specified target within array, or -1 if there is no such occurrence.

   It's open-source, so you can compare [their code](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.java#118) with yours.

   See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries* (The author mentions only the JDK's built-in libraries but I think the reasoning could be true for other libraries too.)

Comment: It was actually supposed to be ii++ thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend naming the parameters `haystack` and `needle` for clarity.  (It's one of the few things [PHP did well](http://php.net/strstr)!)

You don't test your bounds properly.  This test crashes with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
byte[] haystack = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
byte[] needle = new byte[] { 4, 5, 6 };
findString(haystack, needle);
```

The conditional `if(in[i] == find[0])` is superfluous.  Just have the inner loop start with `ii = 0`.

Avoid using variables like `done` pointlessly.  If you're done, and it's possible to return the result immediately, then do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here another implementation, probably more readable:

```
public static int search(byte[] input, byte[] searchedFor) {
    //convert byte[] to Byte[]
    Byte[] searchedForB = new Byte[searchedFor.length];
    for(int x = 0; x<searchedFor.length; x++){
        searchedForB[x] = searchedFor[x];
    }

    int idx = -1;

    //search:
    Deque<Byte> q = new ArrayDeque<Byte>(input.length);
    for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        if(q.size() == searchedForB.length){
            //here I can check
            Byte[] cur = q.toArray(new Byte[]{});
            if(Arrays.equals(cur, searchedForB)){
                //found!
                idx = i - searchedForB.length;
                break;
            } else {
                //not found
                q.pop();
                q.addLast(input[i]);
            }
        } else {
            q.addLast(input[i]);
        }
    }

    return idx;
}
```